# How to change the position of a free action icon in react material-table

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I want to place a freeAction button in [material-table](https://material-table.com/#/) at top-left.
Here is the the illustration of what I want.

[image]

I know it's something like [component-overriding](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/component-overriding). But unable to do that and can't find any example.

Comment: I'm not sure about the actual freeAtcion button, but you can achieve a very similiar position with the Toolbar Overriding Example that it's in the link you've shared, it won't be in the same level of the search component, but at least you have more freedom to position you refresh button by overriding the Toolbar component

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your attention. It was so easy, but didn't find before.
I added an option in Material-Table markup as

```
  options={{
    search: true,
    actionsColumnIndex: -1,
    toolbarButtonAlignment:"left" // here is the option to change toolbar buttons' alignment
  }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have this by overriding the **Toolbar** component instead of using the `actions` property. Below is an example code of the `components` property that you need on your `<MaterialTable />`, you can change the styles and components according to what you need:

```
components={{
    Toolbar: (toolbarProps) => (
      <Box display="flex" alignItems="center">
        <Button
          style={{ marginLeft: '8px', marginRight: 'auto' }}
          variant="contained"
          color="secondary"
        >
          Refresh
        </Button>
        <MTableToolbar {...toolbarProps} />
      </Box>
    ),
  }}
```